# Analyzing TFS Data Warehouse info such as build duration, test duration

Tags: tfs-2015

I have used teamcity and the wealth of information you have access to quite easily in terms of build information like duration (average, shortest, longest), test runs and failures and test durations across branches etc is tremendous. I however am now using TFS and I have access to the TFS_Warehouse table. I have been looking in vain for examples of queries that will pull similar information from that database. Now the information has to be out there somewhere. Can someone point me to any sites with good example queries or pivot tables that pull the build and test information together in a style similar to teamcity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly add a chart to a dashboard in TFS web portal to track these info. There are some built-in chart describe various info. Details you can refer this site: [Add a chart to a dashboard](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/add-a-chart-dashboard)

For more customization, you can also use the **Microsoft Excel reports to display information from the data warehouse** for your team project. Then analysis those data with  various tables, graphics, charts. How to do this please take a look at the [offical tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997876.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, while that's useful I'm looking for specifics on accessing the warehouse tables directly. The links you sent require a lot of effort and access from our IT people which is not forthcoming in a timely manner.